# partitioning integer into almost equal elements

Tags: java, divide

Is there a function somewhere that divides integer or decimal numbers into parts that are as equal as possible and sum up to the input value?

I'm looking for something that would work like that:

`devide(4,2) -> {2,2}` (2+2=4, 2 and 2 are equal)

`devide(6,4) -> {2,2,1,1}` (2+2+1+1=6, no way to make these numbers closer to each other)

I know I can do it myself but I'm looking for some library function.

Comment: I don't know about any library with that functionality, but you should really implement it yourself. It's not that hard and adding a library to your project just for something that simple is a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a library that does that, but it'es quite easy. Just put the quotient in each cells of an array the size of the divisor, then put the remainder in each cell.

Example:

```
public static int[] divide(int n, int d){ //d for divisor
    int[] res = new int[d];
    int qu = n/d; //quotient
    int rm = n%d; //remainder 
    for(int i=0; i<d; i++){
        res[i] = qu;
        if(i  < rm){
            res[i]++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```